# Cannot get user name for a pid using rust winapi

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm trying to get the user that is associated with a PID on windows.

I'm looking at the source for NTop https://github.com/gsass1/NTop as an example.

I can build and debug NTop source on Clion and the following code works correctly.

```rust
HANDLE ProcessTokenHandle;
if(OpenProcessToken(Process.Handle, TOKEN_READ, &ProcessTokenHandle)) {
    DWORD ReturnLength;

    GetTokenInformation(ProcessTokenHandle, TokenUser, 0, 0, &ReturnLength);
    if(GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        PTOKEN_USER TokenUserStruct = xmalloc(ReturnLength);

        if(GetTokenInformation(ProcessTokenHandle, TokenUser, TokenUserStruct, ReturnLength, &ReturnLength)) {
            SID_NAME_USE NameUse;
            DWORD NameLength = UNLEN;
            TCHAR DomainName[MAX_PATH];
            DWORD DomainLength = MAX_PATH;

            LookupAccountSid(0, TokenUserStruct->User.Sid, Process.UserName, &NameLength, DomainName, &DomainLength, &NameUse);

            // FIXME: we cut user name here for display purposes because something like %9.9s does not work with MS's vsprintf function?
            Process.UserName[9] = 0;
        }
        free(TokenUserStruct);
    }
    CloseHandle(ProcessTokenHandle);
}
```

When trying the same thing using rust winapi I get `ERROR_NOACCESS` every time no matter what I do.

Here's some example code that returns `0` as response code from OpenProcessToken and GetLastError will be `ERROR_NOACCESS`. It doesn't matter whether or not I run the program as administrator or not.

```rust
let pid: u32 = 8664; // process that is owned by me but can be any process, it will never work
let process_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, 0, pid);
let mut process_token_handle: PHANDLE = null_mut();
let s = OpenProcessToken(process_handle, TOKEN_READ, process_token_handle);
let last_error = GetLastError();
```

Anyone have any idea why this code would work in NTop using the C api and not work using rust winapi?

Comment: The docs for `OpenProcessToken` say: "The process must have the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access permission." However, you opened the process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`, which as the name implies, is more limited. Try with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` instead?

Comment: Once that is fixed, you'll need to re-read the documentation for [OpenProcessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocesstoken). The final argument expects a (valid) pointer to a `HANDLE`. You're instead passing a NULL pointer. `process_token_handle` needs to be of type `HANDLE`. [MaybeUninit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) can be used here as well, since this is an out-pointer. Either way, you have to pass its **address** into `OpenProcessToken` just like the C implementation does.

Comment: Looks like these suggestions were correct.

The key was to use HANDLE instead of PHANDLE and pass a reference to it.